# MongoDB insert own object id in other field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have objects in a MongoDB collection that looks like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a3137c13d2bf001f4e6a79"),
    "availability" : {
        "stopDetail" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("58b5d30b2fcb13015ea16728"),
                "stop" : 2.414527778,
                "prolongParent" : ObjectId("58b5d30b2fcb13015ea16732"),
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My problem concerns the field `availability.stopDetail.prolongParent` which is intended to store an *ObjectId* relative to an `availability.stopDetail`. In some cases, I want to insert some *stopDetail* objects with their own *_id* in this field (to say someting like "i'm my own parent").

Is there a way to achieve this during the insert phase using some special syntax I don't know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify _id attribute within the document you are trying to insert like below example -

```
db.collection.insert( { "_id": "xyz", "zoo": "animal", ... } );
```

One thing you need to take care is _id should be unique.

Comment: It sounds obvious, though I did not think about it. Thanks.